Create a PDF/UA compliant PDF from an ODT with LibreOffice & Python UNO
Please consider the following example:
import uno

def create_pdf(file_url):

    local_context = uno.getComponentContext()
    resolver = local_context.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
        "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", local_context)
    context = resolver.resolve(
        "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
    desktop = context.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
        "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", context)
    document = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(file_url, "_blank", 0, ())

    # TODO: Create a Universal Accessibility (PDF/UA) PDF

I need to complete it to create a PDF/UA compliant PDF.
If I was doing it from the document in Writer, the steps would be:

Select File > Export As > Export as PDF...
The PDF Options dialog opens.
Check Universal Accessibility (PDF/UA) checkbox.
Click the Export button.

I'm struggling to find applicable examples. Does anyone know how to code this, please?
Thanks
I

Note: The SDK is a separate download with makefiles to run for languages such as Java and C++. It sounds like you're not doing that here, so it would be best to remove that from the title. One important thing about Python is that, since it does not depend on the SDK, the code isn't limited to specific builds of LibreOffice, unlike Java and C++. If you are looking at Python examples from the SDK, those could be linked in the body of the post instead.

I came up with the following:
from pathlib import Path

from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue

def export_doc(doc, output_path: Path, filter_name: str) -> None:

    output_url = output_path.resolve().as_uri()

    properties = [] 
    
    p = PropertyValue() 
    p.Name = 'FilterName' 
    p.Value = filter_name
    properties.append(p) 
    
    doc.storeToURL(output_url, tuple(properties))

I have tried passing it:

"writer_pdf_Export"
"MS Word 2007 XML"

My caution, when it comes to PDF, is that it appears to pick up the settings that were last used in the GUI. So, it will only export a PDF/UA, if that's what was last exported.
In the future, I'll try to make it more robust, but this is good enough for now.
